# How can I attach an overflow cover in a bathtub with no access panel?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, overflow

Years ago, the builders put the bathtub in the wrong way so that it abuts tile in the bathroom behind it. The only way to put in an access panel or to access the pvc behind the tub would be to either remove the tub and/or tile, an expensive and time consuming process.

Is there an overflow cover that will just snap on with no screws?

I have attached a picture of my predicament.

[image: Overflow drain with no access to install new pvc fitting]

Comment: Is the overflow connected to the drain? the fitting looks ??? to me.

Comment: Yes, it's connected to the drain. The fitting is plastic that came with the tub.

Comment: That looks like no overflow that I have ever seen.  Are we sure the builders installed that correctly?  What is that cap for with an o-ring?  Water is _supposed_ to get into the overflow...

Comment: I have seen some with holes in the front in brass and nickel but these screw on also. could you drill some holes in it so it would work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need access from the back.

Usually the overflow tube is accessed from the bottom. If you can get to the trap then you can get to the overflow.

The trap and overflow tube come as an assembly and the overflow tube usually has two threaded bosses to mount your overflow drain cover and a rubber gasket that goes up against the back of the tub to seal it. You don't need to drill any holes in the tub itself.

Look for a new tub trap assembly with the drain and overflow included to suit your bathroom trim design (polished chrome, brushed nickel, etc.).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post obviously. But I will post this response in case anyone else stumbles by it and has the same drain assembly (common in spa tubs or other pre-assembled tub units).

You need a snap-on type overflow cover. Watco makes one with a conversion kit, though you won't need the conversion pieces. The cover should just snap on over the corners of that hexagonal piece on the drain pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ed Beal. Drill some holes in it **after** you get a decorative plate or strainer that fits over (1-screw mounting) or even around it (2-screws mounting). Preferably, it would just have a bunch of round holes in it.

First, you'd drill the mounting screw hole(s) & actually attach the cover. Then, you'd use the holes in the cover as your template & just drill those out.

Now, if you want one of those fancy covers that has an invisible hole or slot on the bottom side. You'd get a 2-screw cover, so you can unscrew everything in the future. You'd screw everything on nice & hand tight to than drill out the entire plastic setup right through the bottom threads & everything, matching the cover's hole or slot as closely as you can.